# Layer not visible under Raster Calculator but visible in the Tree Panel

Tags: pyqgis, layers, qgis-processing, raster-calculator

I have one raster layer(generated inside a plugin) visible under the Tree layers panel and on the canvas but not in the Raster Calculator processing tool.

I can replicate the same behavior with the following code:

```
def iterate_all_layers():
for k, layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().items():
    # TODO: Do something interesting with the layers
    print(layer.name()) 
iterate_all_layers()   **#the layer is NOT visible**


def iterate_toc_layers(group):
for tree_layer in group.findLayers():
    # TODO: Do something interesting with the layers
    print(tree_layer.layer().name())
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
iterate_toc_layers(root)  **#the layer is visible**
```

The layer is generated with the following code:

```
calc = QgsRasterCalculator(
        formulaString=f"ras@2 {operator} ras@1",
        outputFile=output,
        outputFormat='GTiff',
        outputExtent=layer1.extent(),
        nOutputColumns=layer1.width(),
        nOutputRows=layer1.height(),
        rasterEntries=entries,
        #transformContext=tc
    )
calc.processCalculation(feedback=feedback)

out_layer = QgsRasterLayer(output, layer_out_qname)
layer_group.insertChildNode(level_in_group, QgsLayerTreeLayer(out_layer))
```

Layer name: "Raster(test_layer.tif)"

QGIS version 3.27

Any idea why the difference and why I cannot see the layer in available layers running the Raster calculator processing ?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

OK, i ve found an answer myself.
Just need to add an extra step to be visible in processing tools:

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mapLayer=out_layer,addToLegend=False)
```